# Time complexity of nested loop with dependent inner index

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Looking to compute the complexity of the following loop

```
int f(int N) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i *= 3) {
        for (int j = 1; j < i; ++j) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

For the first loop, the values of i are like the following:
1, 3, 9, 27, 81, .., 3^m

where  3^m <= N < 3^{m+1}

Then 3^m = c * N for some constant c

log_3(3^m) = log_3(c*N)

m * log_3(3) = log_3(c * N)
m = log_3(c) + log_3(N)

which implies a complexity O(log_3(c) + log_3(N)) ~ O(log_3(N)) ~ O(log_2(N)) ~ log(N)

for every i from the first loop executed, the second loop is executed 3^(i-1). Following the same reasoning as before, the complexity ends up log(N), so that the overall complexity should be the multiplication of the 2, i.e. log(N)**2.

Is this computation correct for the complexity of these nested loops?

Comment: You can test your theory by running the code with various values of N, and then comparing the value of N with the value returned by `f(N)`. Since you know that the outer loop is O(log_3(N)), I'd use values of N that are powers of 3, e.g. `for (int N = 3; N < 1e9; N *= 3) printf("%9d %9d\n", N, f(N));`

Answer (score 1):

Log3(n) is correct for the outer loop. Big-O doesn't take into account *constants*, so the inner loop, being linear, is O(n). This makes the entire thing O(n log n).

Answer (score -1):

The outer loop is `O(log(N))`, the inner loop is `O(N)` - the amortized geometric row `3 + 9 + 27 + ... + n`, `n` is some value between `N/3` and `N-1`. The overall complexity is `O(N * log(N))`.

It seems there are questions to the sum.

`3 + 9 + 27 + ... + n` is `1 + 3 + 9 + 27 + ... + n - 1` is `(3^n - 1)/(3-1) - 1`, `n is log_3(N)`, thus this is `(N - 1)/2 - 1`, that is `O(N)`.

Comment: You have the right idea, but didn't come to the right conclusion.  `3 + 9 + 27 + ... + N` is less than `2*N`. So the overall complexity is actually O(N). In fact, because of the way the loops are written (e.g. the outer loop ends at `N/3`), the final value of `count` is almost exactly `N/2` when N is a large power of 3.

Comment: @user3386109 No, it does not end at `N/3` in common. Let `N` be 82, then the outer loop finishes on `N-1` equal to 81.

Comment: Yes, your comment is true, but you missed the point of my comment. Which is that the sum is never going to be greater than `2*N`.

Comment: I got it, but I choose `N` from the options of `N/3` and `N-1`.

Comment: If you choose `N/3`, the final `count` is less than `2*N`. If you choose `N-1`, the final `count` is less than `2*N`. So it makes no difference. The final `count` is O(N) either way.